# Change Woocommerce Deposits plugin "Future payments" total to monthly?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce site that requires 50% downpayment on products and 6 Month Plan for the remainders. Woocommerce Deposits plugin does this fine with % breakdown per month but on the Cart **it shows "Future Payments" as the full 50% remainder. I want it to show only the monthly payment**, example Next Month's Payment $XX 

Here's an image to illustrate issue
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtDxi.jpg

I've tried using Loco Translate to change out the wording, but not sure how to make it calculate the $ future Payments so it shows the Monthly Break Down

Comment: Hi, are you wanting to collect automatic payments from customers because wooocomerce deposits does not currently do this you would require a subscription system to do auto payments, if using the subscription system you can add initial fee and then your payment plan and it will show correctly.

Comment: Hi Brad, It's already working doing the payments and initial deposit. I just need it to display the wording so customers understand that it's a 6-month monthly payment.

Comment: ok was just check that you understand the customers will not be charged for the the payment plan automatically and they will be required to pay manually.

Comment: Hi Brad, yes that's correct, it's manual.... here's an example string I'm seeing in translater: %1$s payable over %2$s

Comment: I just need to display %1$s divided by 6